# Azure AD: Trying to login with Auth. Connection to first table returns: cannot_access_publisher_keychain from iOS Maui

Tags: ios, azure, maui

I am trying to retrieve a token from my service and then to access the remote tables with it from an ios phone.

It seems like I am getting a valid token from the service, so Im thinking my config works right. This is what I am getting upon:

```
var x = new RemoteUserService(GetAuthenticationToken);
```

[image]

Now I am taking this token and I am making the first request to the service:

```
var y = await x.GetItemByEmail("55@55.de");
```

This call used to work when no token was required.
But I am recieving this error:

cannot_access_publisher_keychain

I changed my Info.plist to contain:

```
<key>keychain-access-groups</key>
    <array>
        <string>$(AppIdentifierPrefix)com.microsoft.adalcache</string>
    </array>
```

But this didnt change anything about the error.

Do I maybe also need to change somethin here?:

```
   public async Task<AuthenticationToken> GetAuthenticationToken()
    {
        if (IdentityClient == null)
        {
#if ANDROID
        IdentityClient = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
            .Create(Constants.ApplicationId)
            .WithAuthority(AzureCloudInstance.AzurePublic, "common")
            .WithRedirectUri($"msal{Constants.ApplicationId}://auth")
            .WithParentActivityOrWindow(() => Platform.CurrentActivity)
            .Build();
#elif IOS
            IdentityClient = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
                .Create(Constants.ApplicationId)
                .WithAuthority(AzureCloudInstance.AzurePublic, "common")
                .WithIosKeychainSecurityGroup("com.microsoft.adalcache")
                .WithRedirectUri($"msal{Constants.ApplicationId}://auth")
                .Build();
#else
        IdentityClient = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
            .Create(Constants.ApplicationId)
            .WithAuthority(AzureCloudInstance.AzurePublic, "common")
            .WithRedirectUri("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient")
            .Build();
#endif
        }

        var accounts = await IdentityClient.GetAccountsAsync();
        AuthenticationResult result = null;
        bool tryInteractiveLogin = false;

        try
        {
            result = await IdentityClient
                .AcquireTokenSilent(Constants.Scopes, accounts.FirstOrDefault())
                .ExecuteAsync();
        }
        catch (MsalUiRequiredException)
        {
            tryInteractiveLogin = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"MSAL Silent Error: {ex.Message}");
        }

        if (tryInteractiveLogin)
        {
            try
            {
                result = await IdentityClient
                    .AcquireTokenInteractive(Constants.Scopes)
                    .ExecuteAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine($"MSAL Interactive Error: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }

        return new AuthenticationToken
        {
            DisplayName = result?.Account?.Username ?? "",
            ExpiresOn = result?.ExpiresOn ?? DateTimeOffset.MinValue,
            Token = result?.AccessToken ?? "",
            UserId = result?.Account?.Username ?? ""
        };
    }
```

If not, how can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The issue with maui is that there are no entitlements.plist.

Create this file as empty xml:

enter this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>keychain-access-groups</key>
  <array>
    <string>$(AppIdentifierPrefix)com.microsoft.adalcache</string>
  </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Go to ios options and set those as custom entitlements.

and your good to go!

Those DO NOT belong into the info.plist file!